# How can I validate user input in Java

Tags: java, validation

I am currently experimenting with Java, trying to get the user to input an integer. If the user doesn't enter an integer I want a message to appear saying "You need to enter an Integer: " with a completely new input field to the original one.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int counter = 0;
    
        boolean run = true;
        
        int userInput = 0;
        
        while (run) {
        
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            
            if (inputScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            
                userInput = inputScanner.nextInt();
            
            } else if (!inputScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                while (!inputScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                
                    System.out.print("You need to enter an Integer: ");
                    userInput = inputScanner.nextInt();
                
                }
            
            }
            
            System.out.println(userInput);
            
            if (counter == 6) {
            
                run = false;
            
            }
            counter++;
        
        }
    
    }

}
```

At the moment the code above gives an Exception error ("java.util.InputMismatchException"). I have tried to use a try/catch but this doesn't really work because I want the user to see the second message ("You need to enter an Integer") everytime they don't enter an integer and I don't want it to re-loop around the main run loop for the same reason. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, however I am not sure of it. Any help will be massively appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to search before posting your question? What did you find? I found this: [How do I validate input when using Scanner?](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-validate-input-when-using-scanner/) I hope it’s helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would make more sense for the Scanner to use `hasNextLine` and then convert the String to an Integer. If that you could do something like this:

```java
try {
   new Integer(inputScanner.hasNextLine);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(“<error message>”)
}
```

In place of the `if(inputScanner.hasNextInt())` due to the fact that the hasNextInt function will error out if there is not an Integer to be read.